# How to route to parent path while routing in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, lazy-loading

If I define my paths as follows :-

```
   {
    path: 'something/:code/first',
    loadChildren: './modules/first.module#FirstModule'
   },
  {
    path: 'something/:code/first/second',
    loadChildren: './modules/second.module#SecondModule'
  },
```

If I directly route to 'something/:code/first/second' I expect it to first enter the FirstModule i.e. path should automatically become 'something/:code/first' and then if SecondModule path is invoked it should route there. How do I achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `pathMatch:full` or the second module has to be child of first module

```
{
    path: 'something/:code/first/second',
    pathMatch:'full'
    loadChildren: './modules/second.module#SecondModule'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should keep `second` route as a part of `FirstModule`(child route)

```
const routes = [
   { path: 'second', loadChildren: './modules/second.module#SecondModule' },
   ...
]

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      ...,
      RoutingModule.forChild([routes])
   ],
   ...
})
export class FirstModule {}
```

And then `SecondModule` will have the SecondModule related routes, and default `''` path will load desired component.

```
const routes = [
   { path: '', component: SecondComponent },
   ...
]

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      ...,
      RoutingModule.forChild([routes])
   ],
   ...
})
export class SecondModule {}
```